# How does the 'do-release-upgrade' command work with the -c parameter/option?

Tags: apt, 18.04, upgrade, lts, do-release-upgrade

About Ubuntu **upgrade**. After to read some tutorials

Through `Virtual Box` for `Ubuntu Server` **18.04 LTS** with the `lsb_release -a` command appears

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS
Release:        18.04
Codename:       bionic
```

If is executed `sudo do-release-upgrade -c` appears:

```
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
New release '20.04.4 LTS' available.
Run 'do-release-upgrade' to upgrade to it.
```

Until here all is expected.

If is executed `man do-release-upgrade` does not appear the `-c` parameter/option with the expected description - same as [bionic (8) do-release-upgrade.8.gz](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/do-release-upgrade.8.html), but in both places appear

```
 -d, --devel-release
        If using the latest supported release, upgrade to the development release

...

SEE ALSO
       update-manager(8), apt-get(8)
```

Now, about `update-manager` mentioned in the `see also` section - if is executed `man update-manager` then arises:

```
No manual entry for update-manager
```

But through web is possible arrive to [bionic (8) update-manager.8.gz](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/update-manager.8.html) and appears finally

```
  -c, --check-dist-upgrades
              Check if a new distribution release is available
  -d, --devel-release
         If using the latest supported release, upgrade to the development release
```

**Main Questions**

1. Why there is no `man` for the `update-manager` command?
2. How is working the `do-release-upgrade` command with the `-c` parameter/option? If theoretically `-c` does not exist for that command.

**Extra Question**

3. Why is repeated the declaration and description of the `-d` parameter/option, which one is being used by the `do-release-upgrade` command? from itself or from the `update-manager` command?

Comment: Check the source code -- it's a python script. If the source code clearly shows that accepting a -c is intended behavior, then please file a bug report against the `ubuntu-release-upgrader-core` package, that the manpage is missing the -c option. Then feel free to add a patch to the bug report fixing the problem. If the source code clearly shows that accepting a -c is not intended, then file a different bug report. Helping to fix these little papercuts is one of the best ways users can contribute to improving Ubuntu.

Comment: @Nmath at [Upgrade Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04 LTS using command line](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/upgrade-ubuntu-18-04-to-20-04-lts-using-command-line/) see the `Ubuntu do-release-upgrade command-line options` table/section

Comment: @user535733 according with the link shared in the previous comment, `update-manager-core` includes `do-release-upgrade` - now you are mention of `ubuntu-release-upgrader-core`

Comment: Sometime documentation is a little out of date - on my 18.04 box (ubuntu-release-upgrader-core version 1:18.04.44), the built-in doc `do-release-upgrade --help` clearly describes the `-c` option even though the man page doesn't

Comment: @steeldriver and how was updated that documentation? I thought all was based through `apt update` and `apt upgrade` - interesting this scenario

Comment: It's up to the package maintainers - in fact, it looks like it's an already-reported bug [#1798425 do-release-upgrade manual is missing options](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-release-upgrader/+bug/1798425)

Comment: Thanks and interesting this situation